# Masked result from image expression

Tags: google-earth-engine, expression, image

I am writing a code to calculate the Land Surface Temperature (LST), and one of the variables needed for this are the atmospheric factors w1, w2, w3.

First, I added them as a property to each image in an image collection, and used the image.expression to claulate the LST. This method didn't work as the image.expression doesn't accept an attribute in a mathematical operation with an image and gave me an error, as it requires an image. It only worked when I replaced the variables with constant float values.

Second, I tried adding these parameters as bands to the images, but when I map the LST function over the image collection I find using the inspector that the parameters (W1, W2 and W3) and LST maps are masked.

I hope someone could find where the problem is, otherwise I will have to run the code image by image and add the values manually, which is not ideal.

```
//adding WV value as a property and parameters as a property and image band
function addWV(WV, image){
  var W1 = ee.Number.expression('(0.0109 * (W**3)) + (0.0079 * (W**2)) + (0.0991 * W) + 1.0090', {
    'W': WV
  });
  var W2 = ee.Number.expression('(-0.0620 * W**3) + (-0.4671 * W**2) + (-1.2105 * W) + 0.1176',{
    'W': WV
  });
  var W3 = ee.Number.expression('(-0.0533 * W**3) + (0.4013 * W**2) + (0.8585 * W) - 0.0451',{
    'W': WV
  }) ;
  image = ee.Image(image).set('WV', WV);
  image = image.set('W1', W1);
  image = image.set('W2', W2);
  image = image.set('W3', W3);
  var img_W1 = ee.Image.constant(W1).rename('W1');
  var img_W2 = ee.Image.constant(W2).rename('W2');
  var img_W3 = ee.Image.constant(W3).rename('W3');
  
  image = image.addBands(img_W1);
  image = image.addBands(img_W2);
  image = image.addBands(img_W3);
  return image
}

// Land Surface Temperature 
var img = ee.Image(list.get(5));
  var H = img.select('H');
  var E = img.select('EM');
  var W1 = img.select('W1');  //I have also tried .get('W1') as an image property
  var W2 = img.select('W2');
  var W3 = img.select('W3');
  var L = img.select('B10');
  var G = img.select('G');
   var lst = L.expression(
    '(H * (1/E * ((L * W1) + W2) + W3) + G)', {
      'H': H,
      'E': E,
      'W1': W1,// if I set here a specific value instead of W1 it would work like 1.0045
      'W2': W2,
      'W3': W3,
      'L': L,
      'G': G
    }).rename('LST');
```

Comment: Could you provide _runnable_ code? Right now, there's a function `addWV` that's never called, and an undefined variable `list`. If you can create a _simpler, yet complete_ code sample that demonstrates the problem (even if it doesn't attempt to compute anything useful to your goal) then this will help people answer and may even help you understand what's going on yourself.